# Sinusoidal Function Equivalent Equation

Tags: functions

I am having trouble understanding why,

$5\sin(\frac{π}2x−π)+3$

Is equivalent to,

$5\sin(\frac{π}2(x−2))+3$

---

I am doing this on Khan Academy and it says they are equivalent, but I cannot understand why they are. I want to understand this so I can do transformations of sinusoidal functions better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that they are *equal.*

In any case, that's so because the arguments $\fracπ2x-π$ and $\fracπ2(x-2)$ are equal. We go from the first to the second by factoring out $\fracπ2.$ This is more true in general. That is, given a binomial, say, $a+b,$ this is equal to $$a\left(\frac aa+\frac ba\right)=a\left(1+\frac ba\right),$$ provided of course that $a\ne 0.$ Can you now see why the two sinusoidal quantities are the same?

Comment: Can you show a more detailed explanation? Step by step on how to get that solution, the second equation.

Comment: I think I see it. You would multiply the Pi on the right by 2 to get 2Pi, and then divide by pi to get 2?

Comment: @Compilerv2 Yes, you got it. It's just an application of the notion of inverses and the distributive rule. That is, given $a+b,$ you may always multiply this by $1$ without changing it. In particular, one way to write $1$ is as $a\frac1a,$ provided $a\ne 0.$ Then the binomial becomes $$a\frac1a \left(a+b \right)=a\left(\frac1a × a + \frac1a × b\right)=a\left(1+\frac ba\right),$$ by distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It’s simply because $\frac\pi2x-\pi=\frac\pi2(x-2)$. Multiply the right-hand side out for yourself and see.